# awk: copy from A to B and output..?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

my file is bookmarks, backup-6.session

inside file is long long letters, i need copy all url (many) see here example inside

```
......"charset":"UTF-8","ID":3602197775,"docshellID":0,"originalURI":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axxxxxxxxsxsx","docIdentifier":470,"structuredCloneState":"AAAAA.....
```

result to output text.txt

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axxxxxxxxsxsx
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxxxxxxxxsxsx
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxxxxxxxxsxsx
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxxxxxxxxsxsx
....
....
```

there are start before than A `"originalURI":"` to end `"`

comand to be: AWK, SED.. (i dont know what is best command for me)
thank you

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Providing some code to show your effort is the first thing, providing sample input and expected output, both in human readable form, is the second.

Comment: Hi sorry I miss to add information detail, url is various not always youtube, I chose any link for SShow to you then url are many different url because I want to save all various url..so I need command from after "originaluri" until to end do a url..but attention there are url on complete, best after than "originaluri" this is important to save url it okay, sorry for missed information details..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='"originalURI":"[^"]+' 'sub(/.*"/,"",RT){print RT}' file
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axxxxxxxxsxsx
```

Comment: hi i choose this your fix is perfect for me and the result url are correct. thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use grep, for example:

```
grep -oh "https://www\.youtube\.com/watch?v=[A-Za-z0-9]*" backup-6.session > text.txt
```

That is if the `axxxxxxxxsxsx` part contains only letters from A-Z, a-z or digits 0-9, and is not followed by any of those.

Notice the flags for grep:

```
-o, --only-matching
    Print  only  the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
    with each such part on a separate output line.
-h, --no-filename
    Suppress the prefixing of file names on output. This is the default
    when there is only  one  file  (or only standard input) to search.
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but i was missed add information detail, i copy and paste here "
 
Hi sorry I miss to add information detail, url is various not always youtube, I chose any link for SShow to you then url are many different url because I want to save all various url..so I need command from after "originaluri" until to end do a url..but attention there are url on complete, best after than "originaluri" this is important to save url it okay, sorry for missed information details.. " thank you for your help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The awk solution would be as follows:

```
awk -F, '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ( $i ~ "originalURI") { spit($i,add,":");print gensub("\"","","g",add[2])":"gensub("\"","","g",add[3])} } }' filename
```

We loop through each field separated by "," and then pattern match against "originalURI" Then we split this string using ":" and the function split and remove the quotation marks with the function gensub.

The sed solution would be as follows:

```
sed -rn 's/^.*originalURI":"(.*)","docIdentifier.*$/\1/p' filename
```

Run sed with extended regular expression (-r) and suppress the output (-n) Substitute the string with the regular expression enclosed in brackets (/1) printing the result.

Comment: hi for your code with awk result not correct result, see: ":
:
:
:
https://kdenlive.org/2017/03/kdenlive-cafe-15-tonight/
" find one url..uhm.. but thank you for your free help and time :-)

Comment: I acknowledge that you have found a solution but for completeness, I have amended my awk solution adding additional brace brackets to take account of multiple addresses. At least you have a number of solutions now and can see how there are "many ways to skin a cat"